# How to use woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm not a coder but I need to get a second button added to our woocommerce site. On the site we sell books in paperback form but we also want to link to the kindle version. I've used the woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button hook to put a button in next to the add to cart button and you can see it here.

http://theconradpress.com/product/a-loaded-gun/

currently the link simply adds the product to the cart but we want to use a custom link to the kindle version of the book on amazon, the link would obviously be different for each book so is this possible and if so what do I need to put on each page to add the link

This is the code

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','cmk_additional_button');
function cmk_additional_button() {
    echo '<button type="submit" class="button kindle">Buy on Kindle</button>';
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible by add custom link for each product from woocommerce admin.
and get link by this hook by use below code in function file:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','cmk_additional_button');
function cmk_additional_button() {
    $productID = get_the_ID();
    $yourCustomLinkValue =  get_post_meta($productID,'custom_link_meta',true);
    echo '<a href="'.$yourCustomLinkValue.'" target="_blank">Buy on Kindle</a>';    
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just had to add a custom field to the product called custom_link_meta with the url and it worked.